# Identify chemical expressions

Tags: string-manipulation, chemistry

**Background**

I written a chemical equation balancing program.

```
elem=Alternatives@@Reverse@SortBy[StringLength]@Array[ElementData[#,"Symbol"]&,112];
chem=StringCases[#,e:elem~~n:DigitCharacter...:>{e,n}]/.""->"1"&;
group=List@@@Normal[GroupBy[#,First->Last,Total@ToExpression[#]&]]&;
name2mat=group/@chem[ToString/@#]&;

ChemicalSolver[input_List]:=Block[{all,elemts,null},
  all=name2mat[input];
  elemts=Union[First@Transpose[Flatten[all,1]]];
  null=NullSpace@Transpose[(elemts/.Rule@@@#&/@all)/._String->0];
  Thread[input->Transpose@null]
];
```

Give a chemical equation:

$$C_2H_5OH+O_2==H_2O+CO_2$$

The first part `name2mat` change the chemicals to lists, then `ChemicalSolver` calculate the nullspace and find the solution.

[image]

So one of the solutions is :

$$C_2H_5OH+3O_2==3H_2O+2CO_2$$

---

**Problems**

But there are some flaws, firstly it can't recognize the brackets, like `Al2(CO3)3`.

Secondly can't recognize the non-existent element, (These symbols not in [`ElementData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ElementData.html)), a symbol like `Abcd` also can be a kind of element. Some times they'll use abbreviations in organic chemistry.

※ Thirdly can't recognize the ion reactions like `"(CO3)2-"`, this maybe hard, it's `{{"C", 1}, {"O", 3}, {"e", -2}}`, this is not necessary. `ChemicalSolver` still works on this case I think.

※ Small problem, `ChemicalSolver` can't recognize reactant. Output of [`NullSpace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NullSpace.html)'s positive and negative looks random.

---

**Goal**

A function `expr2mat` overcome these shortcomings. Or just `expr2rule` then `rule2mat`.

**Input:**

```
double="C2H5OH+O2=H2O+CO2"
brackets="Al2(CO3)3+H2SO4=Al2(SO4)3+H2O+CO2"
ions="MnO4^{-} +SO3^{2-}+6H^{1+}=Mn^{2+}+SO4^{2-}+H2O"
```

**Output:**

```
{{{"C",2},{"H",6},{"O",1}},{{"H",2},{"O",1}},{{"O",2}},{{"C",1},{"O",2}}}
```

or whole matrix, and I think need 2 list to mark the matrix.

\begin{array}{c|cccccc} 
{}&MnO_4^-&SO_3^{2-}&H^+&Mn^{2+}&SO_4^{2-}&H_2O\\ \hline 
Mn& 1&0&0&1&0&0 \\ 
O & 4&3&0&0&4&1 \\ 
S & 0&1&0&0&1&0 \\ 
H & 0&0&1&0&0&2 \\ 
e & – 1&- 2&1&2&- 2&0 
\end{array}

---

**Edit**

1. Add more input test.
2. `C2H5OH` with double `H` also a possible situation.
3. You can use your own marking if you think that can make things
   easier. For example use `"Ca^{2+}"`represent ions.
4. ※ Consider coordination complex if possible, like
       `"Fe[N(Si(CH3)3)2]3"`or written as `"Fe(N(Si(CH3)3)2)3"`.

Comment: BTW, this is something [WolframAlpha already does](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=C2H5OH+%2B++O2+%3D%3D+H2O+%2B+CO2). So an alternative is to use `WolframAlpha` and related functions. Here is an example of chemical equation balancing: `WolframAlpha["C2H5OH+O2==H2O+CO2", {{"BalancedEquationPod:ChemicalReactionData", 1}, "Content"}]`.

Comment: Interesting, looks it depends on its powerful database, when I try `"Ck2H5OH +  O2 == H2O + CkO2"`, WolframAlpha really confused.

Comment: "looks it depends on its powerful database" -- Yes, of course. "Ck" is not  a known chemical element. So WolframAlpha is not confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the best way to do this would be to look up what others have done in other languages and reimplement that in Mathematica.

That's not what I did.

Instead I wrote an iterative formula splitter that works solely on the basis of three tokens:

1. Whitespace
2. Parens
3. Capital Letters

Here's the code:

```
chemSplit1[s_] :=
  StringSplit[s,
   t : "(" | ")" :> t
   ];
chemSplit2[s_] :=
  StringSplit[s,
   c : LetterCharacter?(Not@*LowerCaseQ) :>
    "!~" <> c
   ];
chemSplit3[s_] :=
  StringSplit[#,
     n : NumberString :> ToExpression@n
     ] & /@ s;
chemSplit[s_] :=

  chemSplit3@*chemSplit2@*chemSplit1 /@ StringSplit[s];
chemNormalize[s_] :=
  s /.
   {
    cap_String?(StringStartsQ["!~"]) :>
     "Start" -> StringTrim[cap, "!~"],
    n_?NumericQ :> "End" -> n,
    "(" -> ("BlockStart" -> None),
    ")" -> ("BlockEnd" -> None)
    };
chemRegroup1[l_] :=
  Block[{splitVal = 0},
   SplitBy[l,
    Replace[
     {
      ("Start" -> _) :>
       (++splitVal),
      ("End" -> _) :>
       (splitVal++),
      ("BlockStart" -> _) :>
       (++splitVal),
      ("BlockEnd" -> _) :>
       (++splitVal),
      _ :>
       splitVal
      }
     ]
    ]
   ];
chemRegroup2[l_] :=
  Block[{splitVal = 0},
   SplitBy[l,
    Replace[
     {
      {("BlockStart" -> _), ___} :>
       (++splitVal),
      {("BlockEnd" -> _), ___} :>
       (splitVal++),
      _ :> splitVal
      }
     ]
    ]
   ];
chemRegroup[l_] :=
  chemRegroup2@
   chemRegroup1[Flatten@l];
chemReform[l_] :=
  Map[
   Replace[
     Replace[
      DeleteCases[# /. (_ -> a_) :> a, None, 2],
      {
       {s__String, n_Integer} :>
        StringJoin[s] -> n,
       {s__String} :>
        StringJoin[s] -> 1,
       {} -> Nothing
       },
      1
      ],
     {
      {a__, {n_Integer}} :>
       {a} -> n,
      {a__} :>
       {a} -> 1
      }
     ] &,
   l
   ];
$chemNameMap =
  {
   "OAc" -> "Oac"
   };
chemPreNormalize[s_] :=
  StringReplace[s, $chemNameMap];
chemPostClean[s_] :=
  With[{revMap = Reverse /@ $chemNameMap},
   s /. {
     o_String :>
      StringReplace[o, revMap]
     }
   ];
chemFormulaInterpret[s_] :=
 chemReform[
     chemRegroup@
      chemNormalize[#]
     ] & /@ chemSplit[chemPreNormalize[s]] // chemPostClean
```

It's mad inefficient and could probably be done with a sophisticated enough [`StringCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringCases.html), but it does get the splits right, even for things that don't exists, like `"Ch"`.

```
chemFormulaInterpret["(Ch4NH3)3(Ch6)2"]

{{{"Ch" -> 4, "N" -> 1, "H" -> 3} -> 3, {"Ch" -> 6} -> 2}}
```

This *would* fail on things like `"OAc"`, but I added a white-list with `$chemNameMap`:

```
chemFormulaInterpret["Cr(OAc6)"]

{{{"Cr" -> 1} -> 1, {"OAc" -> 6} -> 1}}
```

Note that I used nested `Rule` instead of nested `List` as the final form to assuage some ambiguities.

Getting this into your format should be easy enough.

One thing I haven't handled, but which this could pretty quickly be extended to handle properly, is charges. Note, though, that things like:

```
chemFormulaInterpret["SO4-2"]

{{{"S" -> 1, "O" -> 4, "" -> -2} -> 1}}
```

actually work by complete accident.

So if you're willing to invert the way you write your charges (and willing to assume `""` is the tag for `"Charge"`) you should be fine.

Comment: My fault, ions may use special markings like `"^{-}"`or something, then it can be Identify from  equation easier. How to solve this `StringSplit["Ca^{2+}+ HCO3^{1-}+OH^{1-}=CaCO3+H2O", {"+", "="}]`

Comment: And something go wrong with `"Fe(N(Si(CH3)3)2)3"`, I think `chemNormalize` miss the `BlockStart` under double brackets.

Comment: @GalAster seems reasonable. I'll try to patch it up sometime when I've got the energy to do so.

Comment: In case this helps anyone, the code here only works for chemical formulas which uses Integers - i.e. Cu2Cr1. If the notation uses floats e.g. Cu0.66Cr0.33, it fails. The solution for this is to insert another case. That is: "{s__String, n_Real} :> StringJoin[s] -> n" in chemReform, next to {s__String, n_Integer} :> StringJoin[s] -> n.